# How to pass v-model to parent in vue-multiselect

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

i have two components.
One is `vselect` template and wrapper for `vue-multiselect`.

```
<template lang="pug">
  field-wrapper.field(:label="label" :caption="caption" :error="error")
    multiselect(v-model="value" :options="options")
</template>
```

Second is `page.vue` where im including it

```
vselect(v-model="select.value" :options='select.options')
p {{ select.value }}
```

But v-model works only inside vselect, how i cant pass selected data to `page.vue`, from vselect? I cant use new method for emit in `page.vue`. Vue-multiselect works only with v-model i guess?

When i have a case with input, what works for me

```
<template lang="pug">
  field-wrapper.field(:label="label" :caption="caption" :error="error")
    input.form-input(:type="computedType" :value="value"  :disabled="disabled" :placeholder="placeholder" @keyup="removeError" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)")
</template>
```

`@input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)` - i solve problem like this, but ints not work with plugin vuemultiselect

Comment: when im using v-model two times i had error: vue.esm.js:628 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"

Comment: just do `@input="$emit('input', value)`